# How can I see which DLLs included in Windows contain icons?

Tags: windows, icons, dll

When changing shortcut icons it's useful to know which DLLs and EXEs included with Windows contain icons, but there are so many DLLs (especially in System32) that it's difficult to find the ones which contain useful icons.

Which DLLs or EXEs included with Windows (any flavor) contain icons?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [IconsExtract](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html) from NirSoft.

It scans a folder you select and can list any icons and files which contain icons.

[image]

Comment: Nice! I will make sure to check that out. Beats searching through DLLs manually.

Comment: Nir Sofer never disappoints. :-)

Answer (score 50):

**Big ones:**

```
%windir%\system32\shell32.dll           Standard
%windir%\System32\wmploc.DLL            OK
%windir%\system32\setupapi.dll          OK, Hardware / Periphals
%windir%\system32\ddores.dll            OK, lot of devices
%windir%\System32\ieframe.dll           IE and warnings, mixed ugly
%windir%\system32\netshell.dll          Ugly and non ugly
%windir%\System32\imageres.dll          Ugly, New ones
%windir%\System32\pifmgr.dll            Ugly, Win95 Ones
%windir%\System32\moricons.dll          Ugly, very old
%windir%\System32\mmcndmgr.dll          Ugly, Very old
%windir%\System32\compstui.dll          Ugly, Very old
```

**Small ones:**

```
%windir%\system32\accessibilitycpl.dll
%windir%\explorer.exe
%windir%\system32\gameux.dll            Some gaming icons
%windir%\system32\mmres.dll             Audio
%windir%\system32\mstscax.dll           Warnings
%windir%\System32\netcenter.dll         Network
%windir%\System32\networkexplorer.dll   
%windir%\system32\networkmap.dll
%windir%\System32\pnidui.dll            Ugly Exlamations
%windir%\system32\SensorsCpl.dll        Handheld devices
%windir%\system32\xpsrchvw.exe 
%windir%\system32\UIHub.dll
%windir%\system32\vpc.exe
        - provided as a free download for Win7 owners
%windir%\system32\wmp.dll               Media player
%windir%\system32\wpdshext.dll          Battery and arrows
%windir%\system32\wucltux.dll
```

Comment: Emanuel, Can I complete that list or you want me to make another post? I like to share knowledge, that's all.

Comment: Feel free to add more

Comment: Done. I hope you don't mind the re-ordering and adding comments.

Comment: I couldn't find the Device Manager's icon in the above files. Any idea where it may be? (Using Win 8.1)

Comment: Some heroes don't wear capes

Comment: My Windows 10 says no icons in gameux.dll, wmploc.dll

Comment: loads of these don't modify the icon in Windows 11 (for a folder in windows explorer). imageres.dll and shell32.dll seem to work well but many others just leave a standard folder icon

Answer (score 8):

The classic additional icon repository of Win95 is `%SystemRoot%\system32\moricons.dll`. The file is still included with Windows 7.

Comment: Win95 ?????????

Comment: Or maybe it was Win98, don't remember any more. The one that had real DOS underneath... Actually, I think those icons are/were basically for DOS programs.

Comment: I noticed that on my Win7 system....so it's still there!

Comment: It is on my VM with Windows 3.1, so it has been around at least since then.

Comment: ...and it still exists as of Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows 10 v1903, icons have been moved from `C:\Windows\System32\some-file.dll` to **`C:\Windows\SystemResources\some-file.dll.mun`** (not .mui). See [this other SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/1480268/icons-no-longer-in-imageres-dll-in-windows-10-1903-4kb-file) and [Microsoft's website](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/where-are-the-icons-for-windows-10018362-1903/2cc12785-3f83-4f53-8f6d-1a1bd343073f).

[MiTeC's Icon Explorer](https://www.mitec.cz/iconex.html) is a free and convenient tool to search through folders and identify files with icons. It also appears to be smart enough to search `C:\Windows\SystemResources` instead of `C:\Windows\System32`.

---

**Note 1:** One limitation I found: MiTeC's Icon Explorer shows icon *indices* but not icon *IDs*. If you're using the Windows Registry to find/edit links to a specific icon DLL, and the icon number has a negative sign, then the number refers to the ID of the icon, not its index. See [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100505-00/?p=14153) and [there](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-extracticona) for more detail.

**Note 2:** `gameux.dll.mun` doesn't exist in `C:\Windows\SystemResources`, maybe because the Games folder was removed in Windows 10 v1803: see [this article](https://winaero.com/blog/games-folder-windows-10-spring-creators-update/). A game folder icon still exists in `imageres.dll.mun` though (index 177, ID 186).

Answer (score 0):

NirSoft has their own library for record keeping for the icons in dll files for older versions of Windows particularly 7 and 8:
https://www.win7dll.info/
https://www.nirsoft.net/dll_information/windows8/

A more recent reference can be found in the TechNet:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6b53a304-4110-4ae3-bff1-8dd7ac46a106/default-icon-library-for-windows-7-amp-all-windows-10-versions

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).