# What and where is the dll that has these icons in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, icons, dll

What is the DLL that has these icons (play, stop, pause), or something like this, and where is it located in Windows 7?

[image: icon preview]

Comment: they look custom, is there any more info on the icons?

Comment: I've never seen those in Windows 7 and they certainly don't look like the native OS look. I guess they belong to something else.

Comment: Icons Land Vista Play Stop Pause Icons Demo! Part of them are present here.. Aren't they present on somewhere on Win7 also?

Comment: As seen in http://superuser.com/questions/142731/how-can-i-see-which-dlls-included-in-windows-contain-icons IconsExtract from NirSoft will permit you to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only place I see these is at the [Icons-Land site](http://www.icons-land.com/vista-play-stop-pause-icons.php).
They have a $40 price tag there... wouldn't expect them to be already present in Win7 somewhere.

```
Version:    1.0
Series:     Software Icons, Web Icons
Count:   17
Variations: 459
Formats:    .PNG, .ICO on request
Colors:     TrueColor + Alpha
Sizes:   16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64, 128x128, 256x256
Price:   40 USD
```

Comment: Hm... They're copied from the Icons-Land site from a folder called 'images/products', so I think they're icons sold by them. http://www.icons-land.com/images/products/VistaPlayStopPauseIconsPreview1.jpg