# How can I use Windows Libraries icons for my own folders?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, icons, windows-libraries

I relocated my Windows Libraries to a set of folders of my own:

[image]

Now I also want to use the same icons for these folders. How can I do that? I tried Customize under the folder's properties, but I can't seem to find the icons in `shell32.dll`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icons for Music, Pictures and Videos are located in `%SystemRoot%\system32\wmploc.dll` and the icon for Documents is located in `%SystemRoot%\System32\imageres.dll`:

[image] [image]

[image]

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/142732/486213) for a list of DLL files containing icons.

Comment: You're very welcome. I edited my answer to include a link for another answer here on SU that contains a list of DLL files containing icons.