# Icons no longer in imageres.dll in Windows 10 1903 - 4kb file

Tags: windows-10, icons

This has been around since for ever, now it's a 4kb file.  Where did MS decide to stash all the icons?  I use them when illustrating user manuals and this is a big deal not having access.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In earlier Windows builds, icon resource files were embedded in some DLL
in the directory `C:\Windows\System32`.
Since Windows 10 version 1903, they have been relocated to:
`C:\Windows\SystemResources`.

There is now a new extension for these files `.mun` instead of `.mui`
(which still exist in `system32` and `syswow64` sub folders.

Specifically, `imageres.dll` is now found in
`C:\Windows\SystemResources\imageres.dll.mun`.

You now can edit icons from `SystemResources` more easily, as there are no
digital signatures to worry about or `syswow64` and `system32` files to edit.
There are still some files in `system32` that contain icons,
but most have been relocated.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it. 

To use an icon extractor I copied it to the desktop, removed the .mun extension and it worked.  So it's basically a DLL with a new extension appended.

Comment: I was able to directly drag and drop the `.mun` files from the `SystemResources` folder into my icon editor and extract the icons.