# What is a .dll.mun file?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm trying to find out why a program refuses to start on a particular computer. The error is:

> LoadLibrary failed with error 87: The parameter is incorrect.

Which usually means that a dll is not available, either one that the program itself loads, or one of the dependencies of such a dll.

I have used Process Explorer to find the culprit and the last entry is

```
CreateFile c:\windows\SystemRessourcs\user32.dll.mun
```

That file indeed does not exist. There are many other files of the form *somename.somecommonextension.mun* in that directory.

I googled for that file name, but found nothing that helped.
The file content looks like a regular dll.

Can anybody tell me what a .mun file is?

Comment: Found some info here and on Google... [example](https://superuser.com/a/1480287/1773228)

Comment: MUN files are icon files in Windows 10 / 11.  Have you got an app that does not have a proper icon?

Comment: This is about an error message I get from a program when I start it. No idea why it tries to access this file. It's possible that it tries to load an icon for displaying it on a form, but I simply don't know.